# Patch or update foreign keys (ID) in existing Rails Postgresql table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, duplicates, associations

Postgresql 9.5, Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.3.0

SlIMMED-DOWN for downvote (too wordy?)

I've tried using activerecord-import etc while bulk importing data and honoring associations and avoiding duplicates--to no avail. So, instead of linking associations during import, I was wondering if it's possible to do after import, i.e. on existing records only?

Central question: **Is there a way to take junky, linked-to-nowhere foreign keys (foreigntable_id) in a table and update/replace them with the pristine primary keys (id) of its associated table?**

UPDATE: d'oh, this may be found by tweaking SQL generated by Rails' `update_all`.

Answer (score 0):

So, Rails' `Model.update_all(id: ...)` method gave some good clues to a way (not sure if great way) to update foreign keys (or any column). If we have an Investor model and table `investors` that `has_many` `transactions`, and `transactions` `belongs_to` `investors`, and `investors` table has a unique `name` that is the same as, say, the `transactions` table `inv_name`:

```
UPDATE transactions 
SET investor_id = (SELECT investors.id FROM investors
                  WHERE investors.name = transactions.inv_name)
WHERE transactions.id IN (SELECT transactions.id FROM transactions)
```